# Custom added font IDAutomationHC39M is not working in mpdf

Tags: php, fonts, mpdf

I am generating invoice using mpdf.
but barcode is not working.
I am using font IDAutomationHC39M for barcode

I integrate IDAutomationHC39M font to mpdf through bellow steps : 
**1. I uploaded IDAutomationHC39M.ttf to  mpdf/ttfonts/**  
**2. Then i updated mpdf/config_fonts.php font array**

```
 "IDAutomationHC39M" => array(
    'R' => "IDAutomationHC39M.ttf"
    ),
```

now look my final code :

```
<?php
$html = '
<html><head><style>
body {font-family: IDAutomationHC39M; font-size:30px;}
</style></head>
 <body>38329638</body>
</html>';


$mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4', '8', '', 10, 10, 22, 22, 10, 20);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
?>
```

But it is not working. 
   **It look like bellow image**   
  [image: Currently it is looking as]

```
But it should like this :
```

[image: It should like this]